# Can not connect to kafa cluster from istio

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, istio

We have a Kafka cluster in ec2. We have ec2 ip's as listeners and advertised.listeners in server.properties. (we don't have DNS resolution yet). We have MS in ec2 and k8s both with can connect to this kafka cluster and operate.

Now i am trying to setup istio in k8s. I have created DNS entry in route53 which will resolved to all kafka ip's and added ServiceEntry in istio. which should open port from envoy to kafka.

The problem is **I can do kafka topic listing from istio but can not produce or consume.**. DNS is getting resolved and kafka port is open from istio

I am suspecting we need to change advertised.listeners to DNS or i have put ip of all cluster. I couden't find any solution from istio to kafka. Also zookeeper service entry is not added do i have to add that also i am i am only connecting to kafka using sarama lib?

Any help is appreciated.

kakfa is 1.0.1 
istio is 1.1.7

I have added producer error.

```
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,494] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 26 on topic-partition test-0, retrying (2 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,495] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received unknown topic or partition error in produce request on partition test-0. The topic-partition may not exist or the user may not have Describe access to it (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,597] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 28 on topic-partition test-0, retrying (1 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,597] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received unknown topic or partition error in produce request on partition test-0. The topic-partition may not exist or the user may not have Describe access to it (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,704] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Got error produce response with correlation id 30 on topic-partition test-0, retrying (0 attempts left). Error: UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,704] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received unknown topic or partition error in produce request on partition test-0. The topic-partition may not exist or the user may not have Describe access to it (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,808] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 0 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
[2019-06-21 12:41:13,809] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Received unknown topic or partition error in produce request on partition test-0. The topic-partition may not exist or the user may not have Describe access to it (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
```

Comment: Can you publish your service entry? (without the exact IPs).

Comment: apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  hosts:
  - kafka.example.net
  exportTo:
  - "."
  ports:
  - number: 9092
    name: tcp
    protocol: TCP
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  resolution: STATIC
  endpoints:
  - address: <ip1>
  - address: <ip2>
  - address: <ip3>

Comment: @VadimEisenberg I got a workaround for same. When i put "location: MESH_EXTERNAL resolution: STATIC" and provide endpoint things start to work but when i put "location: MESH_EXTERNAL resolution: DNS" it start above error. I have rout53 entry which is resolving.

Comment: OK, I am glad you found a workaround and it works for you now.

Comment: @vadim, I found it but i am not happy about it. I don't like having hardcoding ip's as our Kafka is getting bigger we have to manually add ip address in service entry. Cassandra working with resolution as dns.

Comment: The problem is that In TCP there is not such concept as Host header, the proxy can only see the IP address for TCP.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install your kafka cluster in a namespaces without `istio-injection` label. With this you should bypass the sidecard and get communication easier.

remember read this once you start deploying multiple services https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/requirements

Comment: We have kafka in aws ec2 not in k8s and we are not planning to move now as there are legacy system depend on that kafka.